# Double quotes rendering before paragraph in XHTML export

Tags: lyx

With LyX 2.1.2 on Linux and Windows, Document class is Book (Standard class).

Input:

```
"Hello"
```

LaTeX source for paragraph:

```
``Hello''
```

XHTML output (as viewed, and as copied to clipboard)

```
<body>
&ldquo;<div class="standard"><a id='magicparlabel-221868' />Hello&rdquo;</div>
</body>
```

Which looks a bit like this:

```
“
Hello”
```

What can I do to stop the left quotes from appearing outside the <div>?

This only started happening when I upgraded from 2.0. The Windows install is a fresh one with no pre-existing layout files or anything.

It's pretty serious, because I need the XHTML intermediate files to convert to MOBI and EPUB.

Comment: I can reproduce. This is a bug in LyX (in my opinion). Can you please post a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: Note that we are working on releases 2.1.3 and 2.2 so if you report it there's a chance we could fix it by then.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. For archival purposes, the bug was reported at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9383